# Alternating div line dividers with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, divider

I am trying to find out if there is a way to alternate content line separator colors if possible.

For example: [image]

The issue is that it has to be something automatic, so I'm assuming javascript would probably be required, but I can't find anything like this.  I know there is some things that show you had to alternate if you have something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004537/css-div-alternating-colour). I say it has to automatically change because I'm using wordpress so one single line/snippet of code will be entered and something like javascript will need to automate the process. Any idea's?

Comment: Your question only begs for more questions: (1) What would your markup be like? Are you going to use the `<hr />` element as a separator? (2) What are the colours do you want to generate? Are they generated dynamically, or you simply have to alternate between `n` colours?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily require JavaScript, it can be done with css. But you should show some of your html and css to receive help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<hr />` elements between paragraphs as separators and style their colors with setting  `border` CSS property.

***CSS :***

```css
body{
   text-align:center;
}

hr{
    width:80%;
    border-radius:5px;
}
hr:nth-of-type(1){
    border: 4px solid red;
}
hr:nth-of-type(2){
    border: 4px solid yellow;
}
hr:nth-of-type(3){
    border: 4px solid green;
}
```

***Screenshot :***

[image]

***Example :***

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DXWeF/3/)

Comment: -Got it! I added the hr tag before the end `<?php endwhile; ?`>.Alright, this works fine if it's altogether and there are not any breaks with the paragraph/code, but now I'm trying to get it to work with wordpress, which I am only putting one single `<hr />` in the main index template. Is there a way to get it to work like that? I've opened up my website to hopefully show it better: [link](http://hateyourway.org/)

Comment: @user1816981 :  I wish I could help you, but I am not familiar with `WordPress`, so you better ask another question (include html,css, fiddle and desired result).

Answer (score 0):

Here's something for starters: http://jsfiddle.net/3wGBb/

Take a look if your required browsers support `nth-of-type` CSS3 selector: http://caniuse.com/css-sel3.