# CSS span alternating colour with children

Tags: html, css

I've got a dom structure which is generated by a JS framework and may looks like this:

```css
span:nth-child(odd) { background-color: lightblue; }
span {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>

  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to color the span alternatively no matter if the parent is the same or not.
I gave it a try with pseudo selectors and this question [CSS div alternating colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004537/css-div-alternating-colour), with no luck. Is this achievable with CSS only or should I dig into a JS framework solution based?

Comment: JS is certainly the easy approach, I don't believe this is possible (with a dynamic structure) in just CSS.

Comment: if all of them have the same height, we can find workarounds

Comment: @TemaniAfif, are you thinking of a linear-gradient as the parent's background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there's a cross-browser CSS-only solution so I recommend using a little bit of Javascript.

Using the `querySelectorAll()` of the Document interface we can get a list of elements matching the query requested by a selector passed to the function.

So if we want all `<span>` elements:

```
document.querySelectorAll("span")
```

If we now go further and transform the returned `HTMLCollection` into an array, we can filter out the even or odd elements and add a CSS class using the `element.classList.add()` function.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("span")).forEach((element, index) => {
  if (index % 2 == 0) {
    element.classList.add("background");
  }
})
```

```css
.background {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors with the previous span no matter if it's the same parent or not</span>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <span>Some text to color in alternate colors</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but the answer I needed. Thanks